# Why was this closed?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, closed-questions, close-reasons, reopen-closed

Below is [my question that was closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13730301/where-did-the-estimation-rule-of-thumb-originate-that-time-spent-will-be-one-thi).  I feel this is a valid question for SO.  This seems to be happening too frequently to questions that shouldn't be closed.

> Where did the estimation rule of thumb originate that time spent will be one-third in each of the following: design, implementation, and testing? [closed]
>   I commonly hear that one-third of a projects time will be spent in design, one-third in implementation, and one-third in testing. The three phases of development seems to be derived from the waterfall model. But, where did the time division originate (1/3, 1/3, 1/3)? Is there a paper or book that this is from?

Comment: You should include a link to the question instead of the full text. Also, please let us know why you think it shouldn't be closed.

Comment: As the closure message states, this is off-topic. It is not a practical programming problem that you face. I.e. there is no code involved.

Answer (score 15):

If you try to look at it from an answerer's perspective, the only way they can answer this is to provide anecdotal evidence of how they think the practice or philosophy evolved. Since SO is not a site for historians of design practices, your question is off topic there.

This is not to say your question is Bad. I believe your question would be more suited for a site like [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com), which is:

> A collaboratively edited question and answer site for professional
>   programmers interested in **conceptual questions** about software
>   development

That sounds much closer to what you were going for, no?

Comment: It would be a better fit for Programmers than Stack Overflow (ProgSE mod here).

Answer (score 6):

BoltClock was kind enough to migrate the question to Programmers, you'll have to create an account to the site and link it to your Stack Overflow account to get ownership of the question.

Since you are new to the site, please read the [FAQ](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq) thoroughly to see what the site's about and what questions we welcome (and what we could live without). Browsing our [Meta FAQ questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq?sort=votes&pagesize=50) will also be very helpful in understanding what the site's about (it can be a bit confusing at first).